# How to replace the current url without refreshing the page in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to replace the current url of the page without refreshing the page in angular 11.

I have tabs in my page on click on each tab i want to append the clicked tab name prefixed with # in addition to current url.
here i am getting the currenturl checking if # is appended if yes removing it and adding the clicked phase else
but this is not working fine it is not getting to the correct place only some tabs are working any other way to replace the url without refreshing but note url is getting replaced fine but it is not navigating to expected id.
html:

```
<a href="#{{phase.TitleNew}}" title="" (click)="tabClick(phase.TitleNew)">{{phase.Title}}</a>
 <div class="c-arquetype-phase__block -one" id="{{data.Phases.TitleNew}}">
```

I used this is ts

```
 tabClick(phase: any) {

this.flag = 1;
if (this.flag == 1 && this.router.url.includes('#')) {
  let hashIndex = this.router.url.indexOf('#');
  this.finalUrl = this.router.url.substr(0, hashIndex);
  this.finalUrl = this.router.url.substr(0, this.router.url.lastIndexOf("#"));
}
else {
  this.finalUrl = this.router.url;
}
this.hrefUrl = this.finalUrl + '#' + phase;
this.archetypePhases.forEach(data => {
  if (data.TitleNew === phase) {
    data.isClicked = true;
  }
  else {
    data.isClicked = false;
  }
})
this.location.replaceState(this.finalUrl + '#' + phase);
```

}

Comment: Take a look at the router navigateByUrl method https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl

Comment: I don't want to go to new page i just want to update current url

Answer (score -1):

The built in functionality of hash anchors should both append the #content in the URL and auto scroll to it without using any of that TS code. (As long as phase.TitleNew is resolving to an ID that is present on some element in the page)

```
<a href="./#{{phase.TitleNew}}">Tab1</a>
```

If for some reason that doesn't work you can just set the hash property on the location object with an onclick event like this:

```
<a href="./#{{phase.TitleNew}}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); location.hash='{{phase.TitleNew}}';" >Tab1</a>
```